# Apps Script: Function to Auto. apply Column's formulas when user Inserts a New Row (Above or Below) in a specified Row range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]Good morning,

I'm looking to assemble an Apps Script function that Auto. applies the Column's formulas when a user Inserts a New Row (either Above or Below); in a specified Row range.

For example: I need the Calculation Totals to be retained if a User Inserts a New Row at Row 6 and Row 13. And then, after the row is Inserted, the Calculations or text are auto. applied to Columns J, K, L, M.

```
* Other notes:
Worksheet tab: Planning
Column J (Unit): 'estimate' (text only)
Column K (Sub-Total):     G[row#] * I[row#]
Column L (Sales Tax):     IF(H[row#] = TRUE,K[row #] * 0.13,0)
Column M (Total Cost):     K[row#] + L[row#]
```

I have attached a screen-shot of the Google Sheets tab for context and any guidance on a solution is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I attempted to create an Array Formula, but the spreadsheet requires the Totals listed at the bottom of each section (Sub-total, Sales Tax, Total Cost). And the Array Formula overwrites the Totals at the bottom of each section.

Comment: Maybe you can create an ArrayFormula that only expands until the row with the totals. If you add more context of the sheet (a sample with some dummy data), we'll be able to better help you

Comment: Sure, I have added an image for context. For example, if a user Inserts a New Row (row 6), I need the calculations from row 5 to be automatically added to columns J through M

Comment: And the Total Rows, (example: rows 9, 16, 20), should not lose there calculations when the new row(s) are added. Essentially only auto adding the calculations for a specified Row range: rows 4 - 10, rows 11 - 15, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

ArrayFormula automatically adjusts your range even if you add a new row between the set of rows you already have. But the tricky part here is the "Estimate" value on the Unit Column.

For `Column J` use this formula on cell J4: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I4:I8 + true, "ESTIMATE"))`

**Note:** Defining the condition `I4:I8 + true` is just a cheat way to define a range to be able to set the same text value for the whole range.

For `Column K` use this formula on cell K4: `=ARRAYFORMULA(G4:G8 * I4:I8)`

For `Column L` use this formula on cell L4: `=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(H4:H8 = TRUE,K4:K8 * 0.13,0))`

For `Column M` use this formula on cell M4: `=ARRAYFORMULA(K4:K8 + L4:L8)`

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: Good afternoon @Century Tuna and thank you for your quick response. Your example was definitely helpful and clearly answered by question. Thanks I greatly appreciate it!